# How can I set an image as background for a movie clip in flash/as3?

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, background

I am working on a mini-app in Adobe Flash/ActionScript 3 in which I have to change the color of some objects on the scene by clicking a set of buttons. For the same objects I have to set some patterns (using images).

I can handle the change of the color, but I do not know how to put an image as background.

How can it be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Graphics` to draw the image.

```
// Draw the background
var shape:Shape = new Shape();
shape.graphics.beginBitmapFill(myBitmapData);
shape.drawRect(0, 0, myBitmapData.width, myBitmapData.height);
shape.endFill();

// Reference for later
var background:DisplayObject = shape;
```

You could also use `Bitmap` to display the image.

```
// Display the image
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myBitmapData);

// Reference for later
var background:DisplayObject = bitmap;
```

Now you can add this background to your object.

```
// Add the background at the lowest depth level
myObject.addChildAt(background, 0);
```